# Declaring a property in a Javascript object that ISN'T a string

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to build a javascript object to be passed along to `MongoDB`. This database uses an operator `$or` which lets you search for multiple keys in a property at once.

Because of this, the `$or` operator *cannot* be in quotation marks, because it is actually an operator in the lookup function.

For reference, the lookup function looks like this:

```
db.inventory.find( { price:1.99, $or: [ { qty: { $lt: 20 } }, { sale: true } ] } )
```

I have found a way to 'build' an `$or` property out of some variables, but for some reason the property name keeps being treated as though it's a string. Here's my code:

```
    var criteria = { $or: []};

    properties.forEach(function(property) {
        var propParts = property.split('=');
            if(!(propParts[1].indexOf('&') === -1)){
                var value = propParts[1].match(/[-'"\w\s]+/g);
                    for (var i = 0; i<value.length; i++){
                        var tempObj = {};
                        tempObj[propParts[0]] = value[i];
                        criteria.$or.push(tempObj);
                    }
            }else{       
            criteria[propParts[0]] = new RegExp(propParts[1], "i");
        }
    });

if(criteria.$or.length<=0){
    delete criteria.$or;
}
console.log(criteria);
```

In my console, this is being output as:

```
{ '$or': [ { designer: 'abc' }, { designer: 'def' } ] }
```

I am using similar code elsewhere (with `$push` instead of `$or`) and it works just fine, I'm declaring it in exactly the same way.

Is it possible to ensure that the property ***isn't*** being treated as a string? How can I achieve this here?

Comment: `criteria['$or']` is this returning the object?

Comment: @rps I'm not quite sure what you're asking. It's returning the array, yes.

Comment: I asked that coz I was wondering why you want the property to be an object instead of a string for use when you can get the object itself? thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript object keys are always coerced to strings. That you can specify some keys without quotes in object literals `{key: 0}` or using dot notation `object.key = 0` is merely syntactic sugar for keys that also happen match the production for identifiers.  '$or' is a valid javascript identifier, so you can say either:

```
{$or: [...]}
```

or

```
{"$or": [...]}
```

or

```
{'$or': [...]}
```

and they're all equivalent.

Comment: I figured this was the case. Is there some way to ensure that it doesn't get returned with quotes around it?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The JSON spec (http://www.json.org), which standardizes how Javascript object literals should be transmitted and stored _requires_ all keys to have double quotes, whether they otherwise need them or not.

Comment: Got it, it actually turns out MongoDB doesn't seem to mind if the `$or` is in quotes or not so there must be an error elsewhere in my code!